# Two different networks in a single Active Directory domain

Tags: active-directory, domains

i have Two different NETWORK :

server:
nic 1 : 10.10.11.1 /24 (access to internet)
nic 2 : 10.10.12.1 /24 (access to BD)

client:

nic 1: 10.10.11.2 /24
nic 2: 10.10.12.2 /24

how i can add client with two network in the same DOMAINE

Answer (score 0):

Open Command Prompt and type nslookup, it will help you find IP address of DNS Server.  Since DNS IP address is necessary to connect a client to a domain.

In case, you not find DNS IP address, then open DNS Server and find the IP address of DNS Server.